# Using case_when with multiple true conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

This piece of code

```
library(dplyr)

letters = c("A","B","C")
numbers = c(4, 15, 35)

df <- data.frame(letters, numbers)

df %>% 
  mutate(category = case_when(
    numbers %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
    numbers %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
    TRUE ~ as.character(numbers)
  )
  )
```

yields a dataframe looking like this:

```
  letters numbers category
1       A       4        4
2       B      15     fizz
3       C      35     fizz
```

The outcome I would like to see is this data frame:

```
  letters numbers category
1       A       4        4
2       B      15     fizz
3       C      35     fizz
4       C      35     buzz
```

Since for row C two conditions are true I want to have one row created for each of them. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

`case_when`/`ifelse` would return output for only 1 of the condition. You could do something like this though :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(category = case_when(
    numbers %% 5 == 0 & numbers %% 7 == 0 ~ "fizz, buzz",
    numbers %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
    numbers %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
    TRUE ~ as.character(numbers))) %>% 
    tidyr::separate_rows(category)

#  letters numbers category
#  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   
#1 A             4 4       
#2 B            15 fizz    
#3 C            35 fizz    
#4 C            35 buzz
```

Comment: Thank you but this cannot be generalized well if there are much more cases and any combination of these cases can be true.

Comment: Then, if your priority is to have a completely generalisable method, I thibnk you need to create a separate df that contains the observations that meet each individual condition (using `lapply`, for example) and then `row_bind` the data frames together.  This would be completely general, but not necessarily the fastest solution for a given set of conditions.

Comment: @volfi Yes I agree with Limey's comment. A general solution would be to create a separate dataframe with condition and value. Then loop over condition with `lapply` and return the matched values I think. Maybe add a new question with different example?